# Can't get image to move over to next col in bootstrap grid

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put in a col-md-offset-1 to push the content to right of left arrow by using col-md-offset-1, but the content never moves. I'm trying to get it all centered, but the left arrow is too close to the first bike. I can't seem to figure out why it's not moving since I'm staying withing 12 columns. Any suggestions. [image]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='formApp'>

<head>
    <title>Bicycle App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class='row'>

                <div class='col-md-12'>

                    <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"><span>&nbsp;{{"Bike Shop"}}</span></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                <!-- end class not needed -->
                <div class="chooseTitle">
                    Choose Your Bicycle
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
                <!-- you missed md from offset, end class not needed -->
                <div class="products" ng-controller="BikeController">
                <div class="row">

     <div class="col-md-1"><img ng-src="images/leftarrow.png"></div>
     <div class="col-md-offset-1"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" ng-repeat="product in products | limitTo:-3">
                  {{product.manufacturer}}
                  <img id="bikePic" ng-src="{{product.image}}">
                  </div>
                   <div class="col-md-1"><img ng-src="images/rightarrow.png"></div>
                  </div>




                </div><!--End controller-->




    </div>



    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bikeimageslider.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.header{
    font-style:italic;
background-color:black;
height:60px;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:40px;
position:relative;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left:16px;
margin-left:-10px;
 margin-right:-10px;
margin-top:-10px;

}
.header .fa {font-style:italic;
}
.bikeSelector{
color:green;
}
.chooseTitle{

font-size:60px;

}

.products{
color:  #1E90FF  ;
text-align:center;
font-size:40px;

}
#bikePic{

height:100%;
width:100%;

}
#bikePic, .products {
margin-top:40px;

}
```

Comment: Center the content of the columns with `<div class="col-md-3 text-center">`

Comment: I already added text-align center to the products class via css .products{
color: #1E90FF  ;
text-align:center;
font-size:40px;

} So adding text-center doesn't do anything

Comment: It won't work in the outer div because it's a block element... put the `text-center` on the `col-md-3`

Comment: I updated the code above per your recommendation. I believe this is what you saying. Let me know if I'm still doing it wrong because the page never changes with the added text-center code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nesting with the grid to make the 12-columns smaller which is what you'll need to do in this case to get the entire layout centered...

http://codeply.com/go/4TkFUey6k9

Note: The CSS overrides you have will not work responsively.

Comment: This line of code here <div class="products" ng-controller="BikeController">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1"> What is the purpose of the col-md-11 col-md-offset-1. What exactly is this doing. It looks like it supposed to put all the content in a inner row, but I don't fully understand what this accomplishes, but I want to understand. Can you explain to me how it works?

Comment: It's a column that is 11 unit, offset (pushed over to the right) 1 unit.